# Angular-ui ToolTip: Tooltip hidden by cell constraints in a table

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

If the table cell is defined (and for my design it has to be pretty small without a lot of padding) and I place the tooltip directive on an elements (in my case it is a row of glyphicons so the tooltip is necessary for identification), the tooltip is hidden by the table cell. I have tried to edit the z-index of the tooltip to always show on top of the other elements but I can't seem to find the correct CSS to do this.

So if i define my td tag with min-height: 40px, I can see the tooltip but I can't do this for my design.

```
<td class="staticons">
   <span tooltip="Vote Needed"
      class="pendicon glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign"
      style="color:#009;" ng-if="row.getProperty('need_vote')"></span>
</td>
```

Comment: try using `tooltip-append-to-body`

Comment: yes I think it is `tooltip-append-to-body="true"`